# Using ghc profile with "stack ghc" or "stack runghc" command

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc, haskell-stack

I am during refactoring my project in which i am using stack.

I am unable to build whole project right now, but single files can be compiled and run using

```
stack runghc
```

Stack documentation informs how to pass RTS flags to this command, but I am unable to find how to pass

```
-prof
```

option to compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try something like `stack runghc -- -prof File.hs`. The `--` separates the stack flags from the GHC flags.